# Load bulk data in ignite iggrid faster

Tags: jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

Could you please help me how to load 5000+ data from database faster in ignite iggrid.

We already doing this in json type binding but getting delay of 35-40 sec to load in iggrid.

What is the best to load it faster to avoid performance issue.

Thanks

Mukesh

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the `igGrid` [performance guidelines article](https://www.igniteui.com/help/iggrid-performance-guide) to find out which performance feature is most suitable for your scenario.